# Quick Bug: My profile says my last activity was "3 hours ago"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

Yes, this question is moved from *[Quick Bug: My profile syas my last activity was "3 hours ago"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/504/quick-bug-my-profile-syas-my-last-activity-was-3-hours-ago/505#50)* because this is a platform bug, not a specific site bug. At least that's what I've been told, see the comments.

Basically my last activity is not updating. I have recent activity (recorded) at least 22 minutes ago but my profile on the Beta Sci-Fi & Fantasy site says that my "last activity" was "6 hours ago". It was 3 at the time I posted about this issue on the other meta site.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug; there simply must be a certain period of non-activity before that field changes. It's the "last time you were here", not the current time.

Comment: Oh, isn't that the "last seen" item next to my avatar. I'm taking about the "last activity" under my description. The activities tab are showing all the appropriate activity but the text under the description field is not updating to reflect that activity.

Comment: Also curious... is your profile reputation and the badge count the most you can have? I think its the biggest I've seen.

Comment: Look at his user ID. There must be a reason for the big number.

Comment: so your behind the SE